# Highcharts reset zoom doesn't center data points

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a scatter plot where when you select a point it will create a new graph with different data.  This works fine.

The issue is when you zoom in on the second scatter plot then press reset zoom, the chart resizes and pushes all the data to the left (I'm assuming because all my data points have the same x coordinate or because the values are very small).  I thought by using setExtremes() the reset zoom would use those values as the min and max.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzBxB/5/

Below is the function I'm using to create the new chart.  Do I need to change anything to make the 'reset zoom' register my given xAxis min and max values?

```
function newPoints() {
    var chart = jQuery('#container').highcharts();
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        serie = chart.series[i];

        //sets the new x axis and new data 
        chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 10);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(.001, .003);

        chart.addSeries({
            type: 'scatter',
            name: serie.name,
            data: [
                [.002, 1],
                [.002, 2],
                [.002, 3],
                [.002, 4],
                [.002, 5][.002, 6]
            ]
        }, false);

        //removes the old series
        serie.remove(false);
    }
    //redraws the chart
    chart.redraw();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all values have the same x-value, so Highcharts don't know where to plot them (what is the range of points). In such case I advice to use afterSetExtremes event:

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e){
                if(e.min === e.max){
                    this.setExtremes(.001, .003);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzBxB/7/